# Resize form depending on text length

Tags: c#

I'm developing a desktop application in C#, which shows pop-up messages every X quantity of time. For this, I'm using a library called [PopupNotify](http://benhollis.net/components/winforms/popupnotify/), and I'd like the label that contains the message(called NotifyMessage) to have a fixed width, and vertically enlarge on overflow.

There is an event in which they set this up, but I can't modify it to make it work. Here is the event's code:

```
    private void SetLayout() 
    {
        int padding = 8;
        int iconRightPadding = 0;
        int border = 1;

        iconBox.Left = padding + border;
        iconBox.Top = padding + border;
        iconBox.Width = IconWidth;
        iconBox.Height = IconHeight;

    this.Height = iconBox.Height + 2 * padding + 2 * border;

    closeButton.Left = Width - padding - border - closeButton.Width + 3;
    closeButton.Top = padding + border - 3;

    NotifyTitle.Top = iconBox.Top - 5; //fudge factor
        NotifyTitle.Left = iconBox.Right + iconRightPadding;

    NotifyMessage.Left = NotifyTitle.Left + 1; //fudgy
        NotifyMessage.Width = Width - NotifyMessage.Left - padding - border;
        NotifyMessage.Top = NotifyTitle.Bottom;
        NotifyMessage.Height = Height - NotifyMessage.Top - padding - border;
    }
```

I've tried modifying it's logic, and the way it calculates its height by adding the NotifyMessage's height, and some other things, but none of them worked.

I'll appreciate any help on this.

Comment: More detail on what doesn't work would help. What isn't working? Exactly?

Comment: The standard properties for this (on most controls) are called `MaximumSize`, `AutoSize`, and `AutoSizeMode`. Are these not present? Have you tried asking the developers of that library what they recommend?

Comment: For example: the MessageNotify's height won't vary unless I make the form larger. If I do that, that height will be much superior than the one needing to fit the text.

Comment: drharris: I've tried using those properties. If I use the AutoSize property for the label, it will stretch horizontally, but I need it to stretch vertically.

Comment: try docking that beautiful label...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use TextRenderer.MeasureText to calculate required height of the label.  This should be close:

```
public static int CalcLabelHeight(Label lbl) {
    Size sz = new Size(lbl.ClientSize.Width, Int32.MaxValue);
    sz = TextRenderer.MeasureText(lbl.Text, lbl.Font, sz, TextFormatFlags.WordBreak | TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl);
    int height = sz.Height;
    if (height < lbl.Font.Height) height = lbl.Font.Height;
    return height + lbl.Padding.Vertical;
}
```

From there, set the form's ClientSize property to fit the label.

Answer (score 2):

From my comment:

*try docking that beautiful label*

Comment: Doesn't work as expected. Window should auto adjust to height and width.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
Graphics g = wnd.CreateGraphics();
String s = "Your string";
SizeF size = g.MeasureString(Font, s);
myHeight = size.Height + padding + border;
```

Use StringFormat as an argument to MeasureString to specify wrapping options when calculating the correct height.